# Is it possible to compute the basis of this module?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a polynomial algebra in $n$ variables over field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic zero which is algebraically closed. Assume that $a_1,\ldots, a_n, b_1,\ldots, b_n\in A$ are such that $a_1b_1+\ldots+ a_nb_n=1$. Consider the free left $A$-module $_{A}M$ with basis $r_1,\ldots, r_n$.

From Suslin-Quillen theorem we know that $_{A}M/(A(a_1r_1+\ldots+a_nr_n))$ is free $A$-module of rank $n-1$.

$\bf{Question.}$ Is there any formula of a basis of this module in terms of $a_i, b_i$?

Comment: No, it is what is known as a stably free module, but in general not free. The standard example is the tangent bundle of the real sphere. Let $A=\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ and take $a_1=x, a_2=y, a_3=z$.

Comment: Is there any such examples if $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed. And $A$ is polynomial algebra?

Comment: If $A$ is the polynomial ring, then no such exists, so called Quillen-Suslin theorem, answering a question of Serre. If $A$ is not a polynomial ring, there are many such, even for algebras over algebraically closed fields.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: As I said, this is true, and the characteristic of the field is irrelevant.

Comment: I agree so I think I can delete the question. But is there any algorithm to construct its basis if given polynomials $a_i$?

Comment: "Algebraically closed" is also irrelevant.

Comment: @solver6 please don't delete your question

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(92)90189-S

Comment: So You can post it as answer. This article will be useful for me. I am solving some problem where polynomials $a_i$ are given only by some properties. And I think that there doesn't exist any formula to the basis of this free module and I should use existence of basis only as an abstract result.